# CNN: correct way of reducing dimensionality of last feature maps

Tags: conv-neural-network, pooling

I want to reduce the features of the last convolutional layer of my CNN before connecting it to a dense layer to minimize the risk of overfitting.

Lets say the feature maps of the last layer have the following dimensions :

```
[2, 2, 1024].
```

I want to reduce the dimensions to `[1, 1, 1024]` and don't know if I have to use the average or the sum of these features?

What would make sense? Is there any source where I can read about that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both average and max pooling make sense and are in common use. Using sum instead of average would not generally be an issue, but average is preferable since it can easily adapt to variable feature map sizes.